# Upgrade angular 7 to 8, ERROR: this.typeChecker.getTypeArguments is not a function on Build Library

Tags: angular, angular7, upgrade, angular8, angular-library

After upgrade my complex project based on this [Guide](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0):

When I build my library I got this error:

```
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'my-library'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: this.typeChecker.getTypeArguments is not a function
An unhandled exception occurred: this.typeChecker.getTypeArguments is not a function
See "XXXXXX\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I update Node.js, Typescript  and Ancular.Cli Globally

All steps done successfully.

Should I do something to upgrade my Library separately?

Update:

To build i use this command `ng build my-library-name` with this package `ng-packagr": "^5.4.0`

All library are in one project, and project upgrade with ng update

Node Version: 12.14.1, Typescript version: 3.4.5

Comment: how are you packaging you library?? is it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr

Comment: you have to upgrade all the libraries individually for it to work in your main app

Comment: what is your node version??

Comment: I have the same problem while building library with Angular 6.1.10.

Comment: check my answer, maybe it help you too

Comment: Yeap, it helped, thx.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I find an issue in `tsickle` repository [Here](https://github.com/angular/tsickle).

Based on this issue, angular library raised error when tsickle 0.38.0 installed.

Issue available [here](https://github.com/angular/tsickle/issues/1046).

```
New version of tsickle (0.36.0) gives an error trying to build a library using ng build. Works fine with previous version( 0.35.0)
```

I revert the tsickle to version 0.35.0, and error gone.

Comment: Thanks! - although I only had to revert to **0.37.0** to get it to work.